# Spark SQL - Regex for matching only numbers

Tags: regex, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to make sure that a particular column in a dataframe does not contain any illegal values (non- numerical data). For this purpose I am trying to use a regex matching using `rlike` to collect illegal values in the data:

[image]

I need to collect the values with string characters or spaces or commas or any other characters that are not like numbers. I tried:

```
spark.sql("select * from tabl where UPC not rlike '[0-9]*'").show()
```

but this doesn't work. it produces 0 rows.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`rlike` is looking for any match within the string. The asterisk (*) means 0 or many. 
Having zero numbers somewhere in a string applies to every possible string.
You need to specify that you want to match from beginning `^` til the end of string `$`

```
spark.sql("select * from tabl where UPC not rlike '^[0-9]*$'").show()
```

alternatively you can also match for any single non numeric character within the string `[^0-9]`

```
spark.sql("select * from tabl where UPC rlike '[^0-9]'").show()
```